# Same button for 2 tables selection jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a page and i got 2 tables in that page. I want to pass the value from rows to one .php page but with the same button. My code is this:

**JS code:**

```
 var flag;
function highlight(e) {


if (selected[0]){
       selected[0].className = '';  
       flag='1';
}

else if (selected2[0]){
     selected2[0].className = '';
     flag='0';
  }


   e.target.parentNode.className = 'selected';  
   alert(flag);  
   }


var table = document.getElementById('data-table'),
  selected = table.getElementsByClassName('selected');
var table2 = document.getElementById('data-table-aux'),
  selected2 = table2.getElementsByClassName('selected');



table.onclick = highlight;
table2.onclick=highlight;

$("#tst").click(function(){
   if(flag=='1'){
  var value =$(".selected td:first").html();
  value = value || "Nenhuma coluna selecionada";
   window.open("info_detalhada.php?   data2="+value,'_blank','toolbar=0,location=no,menubar=0,height=550,width=650,lef t=200, top=300');  }
    else if(flag=='0'){
  var value =$(".selected td:first").html();
   value = value || "Nenhuma coluna selecionada";
    window.open("info_detalhada2.php?    data2="+value,'_blank','toolbar=0,location=no,menubar=0,height=550,width=650,lef t=200, top=300');
         }

});
```

**HTML CODE**

**creating 2 tables**

```
<table  style="float: left" id="data-table"></table>
<table style="float: left" id="data-table-aux"></table>
```

(Dynamic tables )

**button:**

```
<input type="button" id="tst" value="Detailed information"  />
```

The problem is that first time i select a row the variable flag will have the old value and not the new value from click.
For example, first time i click a row flag = undefined , second time got the value of the table selected (0 or 1) , if i click on other row the flag wont change and will got the old value (or 0 or 1).

Any tips ? 
Thanks

**edited:** i didnt put the html in first place because i dont think it's an html solution, I dont have a fiddle created because i'm using dynamic table's but i will try to make a fiddle with my example and i will put here when it's done ;)

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/gwg639Lf/9/

Comment: Can you provide HTML and jsfiddle ? Would be helpful

Comment: share your html code

Comment: edited ... i gonna make a fiddle now ;)

Comment: Fiddle added with a example

Comment: Your js fiddle does not have jQuery loaded

Comment: put the final version of fiddle now. forgot to put the jquery script for mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Let me suggest a more generic approach

First of all wrap your tables in a `div`

```
<div class="data-tables">
    <table  style="float: left" id="data-table"></table>
    <table style="float: left" id="data-table-aux"></table>
</div>
```

Then delegate the click event handlers

```
$('.data-tables').delegate('table', 'click', function(event) {
  $this = $(this)
  $this.addClass('active').removeClass('inactive')
  $this.siblings().addClass('inactive').removeClass('active')
});
```

This function does the following:

- Add class `active` and remove `inactive` (if exists) to the selected item/table
- Remove the class `active` and add class `inactive` from all adjacent tables

In this way you will only have one `active` table at the time

Then declare your button handler

```
$("#tst").click(function(){
    var value = $('.active').html()
    // Use the value as you want
})
```

This code will work no matter how many tables you add to the `div`

Comment: Tested in my fiddle example but no sucess.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the class name of the element **after** the condition statement. Hence, the first time, your flag variable is undefined.

Try putting it in the beginning of the highlight function.

```
function highlight(e) {

 e.target.parentNode.className = 'selected';  

 if (selected[0]){
   selected[0].className = '';  
   flag='1';
 } 

 else if (selected2[0]){
    selected2[0].className = '';
    flag='0';
 }
 alert(flag);  
}
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gwg639Lf/10/

**Edit**:

Add it before and after the condition. Adding it before the condition gives you the class name to initialize the flag variable. Adding it after gives the formatting bar.

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gwg639Lf/13/

Comment: That's work good for variable value but not for the .selected color bar

Comment: @No_idea I have edited my answer. Please check it out.

Comment: Adding before and after gives the same problem i had on my 1st fiddle. The value of flag when you change table wont change in the 1st interaction

Answer (score -1):

Ok, after some tests on Kostas Pelelis functions, i found a solution that is valid for my problem.

here is the code of JS:

```
var flag;

$("#data-table tr").click(function(){
 $("#data-table-aux     tr").addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');  
   $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');    
   flag='1';
});

$("#data-table-aux tr").click(function(){
    $("#data-table tr").addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');  
   $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');    
   flag='0';
});


$('#tst').on('click', function(e){
   if (flag=='1')
   alert($("#data-table tr.selected td:first").html());
   else if (flag=='0')
    alert($("#data-table-aux tr.selected td:first").html());
});
```

Here is the fiddle --> [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gwg639Lf/12/)

Thank you all for the help ;)